# python find range of positive element in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list such as

```
[0,0,0,12,34,86,0,0,0,95,20,1,6,0,0,0,11,24,67,0,0,0]
```

I want to find start and end position where element are positive:

```
[[3,5],[9,12],[16,18]]
```

what is the best way to do this in python?
(build in function in python such as: find,lambda,itemgetter and so on.)

Comment: This is not a python question but more an algorithm question ;)

Comment: you're going to have to tell us what you tried elahe

Comment: What's preventing you from writing a `for` loop for this?

Comment: Are there also negative values?

Comment: I want to understand is there a build in function in python to do this or not. my list is very long and using of "for loop" is not time effective!

Comment: @cleb no .values are zero and positive

Comment: @elahe so _O(n_) is not good enough?

Comment: @elahe: what do you mean with non *time effective* enough? In terms of big-oh you the best you can do is *O(n)*, so I don't expect it to be extremely slow...

Comment: @Elmex80s no because this is just a slice of my program and I want to reduce its time complexity

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Won't some kind of bisection method work? Splitting it in half, splitting both half's in half, and so on???

Comment: @Elmex80s: but even then it will still be *O(n)*. You will have to investigate both ends, since there can be ranges in both parts.

Comment: @Thom implement an algorithm in python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And lastly, `regex` version. ;)

```
input = [0,0,0,12,34,86,0,0,0,95,20,1,6,0,0,0,11,24,67,0,0,0]

input3 = str(list(
  map(lambda i_x: i_x[0] * (i_x[1] and (1, -1)[i_x[1] < 0]), enumerate(input))
))

import re
s = re.sub(r'([\[ ]0[\],])+', ' ', input3)
s = s.replace(',  ', '], [')
if s[-1:] != ']':
    s = s[:-2] + ']'
s = '[' + s[2:]
s = re.sub(r' [0-9]+,', '', s)

output = list(eval(s))
print(output)  # [[3, 5], [9, 12], [16, 18]]
```

Comment: oooooo:. very good! this is the fastest and most efficient one. thanks a lot @Sangbok Lee!

Answer (score 0):

Crude `for` solution. :(

```
input = [0,0,0,12,34,86,0,0,0,95,20,1,6,0,0,0,11,24,67,0,0,0]

output = []
pair = []
for i in range(len(input)):
    if input[i] > 0:
        if len(pair) > 1:
            pair.pop()
        pair.append(i)
    else:
        if pair:
            output.append(pair)
            pair = []

print(output)  # [[3, 5], [9, 12], [16, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if ranges can go off the ends of the array or not.

```
def get_positive_ranges(a):
    in_range = False
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if not in_range:
            if a[i] > 0:
                in_range = True
                first = i
        else: # Inside a range
            if a[i] <= 0: # End of range
                in_range = False
                result.append([first, i - 1])
    if in_range: # Tidy
        result.append([first, i])
    return result

print(get_positive_ranges([0,0,0,12,34,86,0,0,0,95,20,1,6,0,0,0,11,24,67,0,0,0]))
print(get_positive_ranges([]))
print(get_positive_ranges([1]))
print(get_positive_ranges([0, 1]))
print(get_positive_ranges([0, 1, 0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 12, 34, 86, 0, 0, 0, 95, 20, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 11, 24, 67, 0, 0, 0]

n = len(lst)

starting_points = [i for i in range(n) if lst[i] > 0 and (lst[i - 1] == 0 or i == 0)]
end_points = [next((i for i in range(j + 1, n) if lst[i] == 0), n) - 1 for j in starting_points]

print zip(starting_points, end_points)
```

output

```
[(3, 5), (9, 12), (16, 18)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a numpy solution, not sure if this is better than a naive for-loop though; see inline comments for explanation.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,0,0,12,34,86,0,0,0,95,20,1,6,0,0,0,11,24,67,0,0,0])

# get indices of non-zero elements in a
nze = a.nonzero()[0]

# check where the differences of these indices are unequal to one; there you have a jump to/from 0
nze_diff = np.where(np.diff(nze) > 1)[0] + 1

# if a starts with 0, add the index 0
if nze_diff[0] != 0:
    nze_diff = np.insert(nze_diff, 0, 0)

# store output
res = []

# loop through the indices and add the desired slices
for ix, i in enumerate(nze_diff):
    try:
        sl = nze[i:nze_diff[ix + 1]]
        res.append([sl[0], sl[-1]])
    # means we reached the end of nze_diff
    except IndexError:
        sl = nze[i:]
        res.append([sl[0], sl[-1]])
```

If you run it for your `a`, you receive the desired output:

```
[[3, 5], [9, 12], [16, 18]]
```

There are probably smarter solutions than this, but this might get you started.

If you want to get the entire range, it simplifies a bit:

```
res2 = []
for ix, i in enumerate(nze_diff):
    try:
        res2.append(nze[i:nze_diff[ix + 1]])
    except IndexError:
        res2.append(nze[i:])
```

Then `res2` would be:

```
[array([3, 4, 5]), array([ 9, 10, 11, 12]), array([16, 17, 18])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the key, you should test which implementaion is the most fast with your very long list. Anyway, this is 'no array acess by index' version, hopefully for boosting speed. And it uses `map`, `lambda`, `index(find)`, if it pleases you. Though, of course it uses `while`.

```
input = [0,0,0,12,34,86,0,0,0,95,20,1,6,0,0,0,11,24,67,0,0,0]
output = []

input2 = list(map(lambda x: x and (1, -1)[x < 0], input))  # mapping by 'math.sign'-like func
start = end = 0
while end < len(input2):
    try:
        start = input2.index(1, end + 1)
        end = input2.index(0, start) - 1
        output.append([start, end])
    except ValueError:
        break

if start >= end:
    output.append([start, len(input2) - 1])

print(output)  # [[3, 5], [9, 12], [16, 18]]
```